# MongoDB complex faceted search not yielding expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build in one aggregation query a *match text search* followed by another *match* query to avoid sending multiple queries to the database, but I am not receiving any result.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
query = await Product.aggregate([
    { $match: { $text: { $search: userQuery } } },
    { $addFields: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
    {
      $facet: {
        Forfait: [
          {
            $match: { Forfait: "midnight" }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]).exec();
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
1. Perform a text search on user input on the collection
2. and also perform a match on the collection on the forfait field
```

The query returns nothing, it seems that it is performing a sort of logical AND query and short-circuits but I don't know how I can perform the two queries in one aggregation.

I have tried following a similar issue here [MongoDB Facet Error pipeline requires text score metadata, but there is no text score available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953662/mongodb-facet-error-pipeline-requires-text-score-metadata-but-there-is-no-text) which reflects my query.

Any directions or help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is what the document model looks just a simple doc

```
{
  id: String
  title: String
  description: String
  forfait: String
}
```

Comment: Please post the input document and the `userQuery` details. Also, it looks like the usage of `$facet` stage may not be required in the above query (a regular match can do).

Comment: @prasad_ I did not quite understand your suggestion. The userQuery is just a search input the user enters, and I as I stated above, I wanted to combine two queries in one, one for the user search input with text search and the other one that just retrieve docs that match forfait: "midnight". Could you please elaborate on your suggestion about only regular match?